# Raspbian, SNMP, physical switches and Log files

Tags: gpio

I'm *most* of the way to solving a project I've been working on and I have got stuck at what seems to be the last hurdle. I'm using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian 8.0, and I'm trying to have it set up for SNMP so that I can query the status of a GPIO pin via SNMP. 
(I used http://www.satsignal.eu/raspberry-pi/monitoring.html as the basis of my code)
I've successfully got the SNMPD running and I can check the "default" SNMP stuff so I know that part is working. My pin checking and circuit are also working and my script that *should* return a SNMP string actually appears to be returning meaningful data.
What isn't working is my custom SNMP line.

When I query the device to check the SNMP status I get:

```
Error in packet
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Failed object: iso.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.8
```

What I cannot find is *why* it's failing. I've had a look in both /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog and I can't see anything obvious.

Where should I be looking to help be diagnose the issue?

(I can attach any file anyone requires, if requested)

Thanks!

Chesh

Answer (score 1):

To begin with try, snmpwalk to test if the agent is responding 
eg: snmpwalk -Os -c public -v1 localhost.If it returns with a list of information,then check the list if the above OID exists.It may be 
just that the correct MIB has to be compiled and loaded

Restart snmpd after adding this line into /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf (or wherever
it was installed)

view   systemonly  included .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've checked the above (Altering, of course, for our community name) and I get lots of responses. Grepping those it's not returning the result so it's definitely the MIB issue. The relevant line from the conf file is:
`pass  .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.8   /bin/sh  /usr/local/bin/snmp-relay-status`